# Query to compare the total sales of one saturday with the average of the other saturdays in the rest of the year

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, timestamp, comparison, average

Hello so I have sales data of daily records for a whole year(ts).  I want to compare one of the Saturday's in 2018, so lets say on December 22nd total sales compared with the average total sales for the rest of the saturdays in the whole year (51 in total).

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT sale_date, sale_total, 
  ROUND((SUM(sale_total) OVER() - sale_total) / (COUNT(sale_total) OVER() - 1), 2) AS sale_rest_average
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM sale_date) = 7
AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sale_date) = 2018
```

it gives you all Saturdays in 2018 with respective averages for the rest of Saturdays in that year

You can test, play with above using dummy data as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT day AS sale_date, ROUND(100 * RAND(), 2) sale_total
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31')) day
)
SELECT sale_date, sale_total, 
  ROUND((SUM(sale_total) OVER() - sale_total) / (COUNT(sale_total) OVER() - 1), 2) AS sale_rest_average
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM sale_date) = 7
AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sale_date) = 2018
ORDER BY sale_date
```

with output like below

```
Row sale_date   sale_total  sale_rest_average    
1   2018-01-06  35.12       42.81    
2   2018-01-13  4.74        43.4     
3   2018-01-20  61.55       42.29    
4   2018-01-27  21.76       43.07    
5   2018-02-03  67.82       42.17    
...
49  2018-12-08  4.22        43.41    
50  2018-12-15  59.46       42.33    
51  2018-12-22  90.86       41.72    
52  2018-12-29  56.92       42.38
```

Comment: Thank you, but I also need to calculate the sales in the query so that would be (unit_price*quantity)

Comment: this was not in your question. your current question is answered so please consider picking the "best" one and accept it - this will increase your reputation and will motivate us to further answer your questions. meantime - check https://stackoverflow.com/a/59107706/5221944

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have one row per day, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select avg(case when datecol = '2018-12-22' then sales end) as sales_20181222,
       avg(case when datecol <> '2018-12-22' then sales end) as sales_other       
from t
where extract(dayofweek from datecol) = 6 and
      datecol >= date('2018-01-01') and
      datecol < date('2019-01-01');  -- Saturday
```